# Python: Tree Recursion Issue

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I have an issue with processing a tree correctly. The tree is simple, just a node and list of children

```
class Tree (object):
    __slots__ = "node","children"
    def __init__(self,node,children=[]):
        self.node = node
        self.children = children
```

Using a linearization technique, though, we are supposed to detect how many (sub)trees a given branch ends. For example, if we construct a tree like so:

```
t = Tree(1, [Tree(2, [Tree(5), Tree(3, [Tree(4)])])])
```

then `t.linearize()` should output `1 2 5 NIL 3 4 NIL NIL NIL NIL`. Each `NIL` represents 1 (sub)tree being ended.

My current version only output the following: `1 2 5 NIL 3 4 NIL`, without the multiple `NIL`s. Any idea what I'm leaving out?

```
def linearize(self):
    print self.node,
    if self.children == []:
        print "NIL",
    for child in self.children:
        child.linearize()
```

Comment: Generally speaking, using `children=[]` as a default is a bad idea... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Duly noted. This was just provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you really want:

```
def linearize(self):
    print self.node,
    for child in self.children:
        child.linearize()
    print "NIL",
```

which gives:

```
In [5]: t.linearize()
1 2 5 NIL 3 4 NIL NIL NIL NIL
```

Right now, you don't print `"NIL"` when there are children.  (And as noted in the comments, you really want `children=None` and then `self.children = children if children is not None else []` or something.)

You might also be interested in reworking this to `yield` each element, rather than merely printing them, but obviously that's up to you.